# Ruber don't start

Tags: ruby, api

When I run ruber on console i got this information:

```
`require': cannot load such file -- korundum4 (LoadError)
```

I have installed korundum4 and any other ruby bindings. I use rvm.

I use: `Kubuntu 12.04`

On IRB is the same error, when I `require "korundum4"`.
My `$LOAD_PATH` for system:

```
["/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1", "/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux", "/usr/local/lib/site_ruby", "/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1", "/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux", "/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby", "/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1", "/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux"]
```

Comment: You installed korundum4 using `apt-get` or RubyGems?

Comment: apt-get, ruby gems hasn't any package name korundum4

Comment: Give us also output of `ruby -e 'p $LOAD_PATH'`.

Answer (score 0):

So as you see, Ruby loads gems that are installed inside RVM. If you want to run your app with system wide libraries you need to switch RVM to system Ruby using:

```
$ rvm use system
```

or read this https://rvm.io/integration/qtruby/ how to integrate QtRuby int RVM (I don't tested this).

Answer (score 0):

I found better solution:

`gem install qtbindings`

Works with Qt4 and rvm.

### My new great solution:

#### dependencies.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $USER -eq 'root' ]]; then
  exit 1
fi

sudo apt-get install libqt4-core libqt4-dev automoc ruby2.0-dev

wget http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/71843/qt4-qtruby-2.1.0.tar.gz
tar -xvzf qt4-qtruby-2.1.0.tar.gz
cd qt4-qtruby-2.1.0

rvm install 2.0.0
rvm use 2.0.0
rvm gemset gui
rvm use 2.0.0@gui

sed 's/Config::/RbConfig::/' cmake/modules/FindRuby.cmake > cmake/modules/FindRuby.cmake1
sed 's/ruby19/ruby19 ruby2 ruby20 ruby200 ruby2.0/' cmake/modules/FindRuby.cmake1 > cmake/modules/FindRuby.cmake2
mv cmake/modules/FindRuby.cmake2 cmake/modules/FindRuby.cmake

sed 's/Config::/RbConfig::/' cmake/modules/FindRUBY.cmake > cmake/modules/FindRUBY.cmake1
sed 's/ruby19/ruby19 ruby2 ruby20 ruby200 ruby2.0/' cmake/modules/FindRUBY.cmake1 > cmake/modules/FindRUBY.cmake2
mv cmake/modules/FindRUBY.cmake2 cmake/modules/FindRUBY.cmake

mkdir build
cd build

cmake ..
make
sudo make install

sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER $MY_RUBY_HOME

cd ../..
```

And after that you can do:

#### app.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'eventmachine'
require 'Qt4'

app = Qt::Application.new(ARGV)
hello_button = Qt::PushButton.new("Hello EventMachine")
hello_button.resize(100,20)
hello_button.show

EventMachine.run do
  EM.add_periodic_timer(0.01) do
    app.process_events
  end
end
```

#### Gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'eventmachine'
```

This way you can use ruby 2.0.0 with smoke and Qt4.

Comment: typo there at gtbindings. should be qtbindings. you could edit this. let me know if you did and I'll delete this comment. Thanks.